# How do I cancel a ticket bought from Czech Airlines webpage?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, tickets

Due to changes of plans I won't be able to use a ticket I´ve booked it online from CSA Czech Airlines homepage. I´ve tried finding out how to cancel the ticket and have emailed them without answer.

How does one cancel a ticket bought from this airline?

Comment: How did you book it? Their website? On the phone to them? From their ticket desk at an airport? Via a travel agent?

Comment: Online from their own site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Call them**.

Seriously, that's always the easiest way to get any changes done with any airline. [Czech Airlines](http://www.czechairlines.co.uk/en/portal/homepage/uk_homepage.htm) does seem to allow passengers to login and see the status of of their ticket; some airlines also allow cancellations using their online system. I didn't find a mention of this in their site help pages but you should give it a go. (You might already have.)

Otherwise, [look up the contact details of the booking office most relevant to you](http://www.czechairlines.co.uk/en/portal/passengers/customer_support/call_centre.htm). If you're [from Sweden, then details are](http://www.czechairlines.co.uk/en/info/rez_kancelare.htm?resoff=STO):

> CSA Czech Airlines
>
> Kungsgatan 37
>
> 5 floor 111 56 Stockholm
>
> +46 8 54 54 54 90
>
> +46 8 58 53 67 69

Comment: Worked perfectly just calling them.